# Operate as root in freeBSD

Tags: freebsd, root

I'm logged in as a user "foo" which is part of group "wheel" after adding  via `pw group mod wheel -m foo`. Where is the difference between:

```
$login
login: root
Password:
```

and

```
su root
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the `login` command will ensure that a new login shell (one that changes the environment variable PATH, USER and many others) is started.

The command `su root` starts a shell but does not change the environment. That could cause some unexpected problems.

A `su -login root` or `su -l root` or `su - root` or simply `su -` will start a login root shell.

A `sudo su -` will start a login root shell but using the user password (not root password).

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/70543) has some additional information

Comment: Can I run only one application as root like `sudo vi file` does for Linux?

Comment: @Hölderlin It is a bad practice to start graphical programs (GUIs) as root like vim. But if you actually mean vi in the command line, no, there is no set limit. You can start as many as you wish. Even with only one console if you end each command with &: `sudo vi file1 &` (send the command to background), then just press enter (if needed) to get the console prompt again and start `sudo vi file2 &`, repeat as many times as you may need.

Comment: Sry my question was not clear enough. What I mean is, if `su` in FreeBSD compare to `sudo` under Linux or how can I act as root without root login, e.g. for just one application like `sudo vi file`?

Comment: The command `su` means "switch user", it allows an user to change to some other (many times root) with `su -l user`. The command sudo should be understood as "switch user and do". To execute `su -` you need the password of root, to execute `sudo su -` (which has exactly the same final effect) you need the user password (and the user has to be included in the sudoers file). Both su and sudo are available in most Unix and Linux OS. But as I have just explained they have different use cases and are not equivalent, similar, but not equivalent.

Comment: @Hölderlin When you say: without root login, do you mean starting a new desktop (X server) and login? That would not be accurate as any time you use the root password or sudo provides its equivalent you are actually login as root. Be it for one shell, one command, or a whole X server session (the whole time your desktop is active). Am I answering your question? Or am I still not getting it right?

Comment: @Hölderlin Well, by similar, I actually mean related but completely different. Sudo allows an user to **run** programs as another user, su allows one user to **become** another user. Those may sound equal, but are not. You can `do sudo -u alice touch file` to update a file as the user alice (the password used is the one of bob, the one running the command). The command `su -c 'touch file' alice` may look the same, but is not. Here what happens is that a shell is started as user alice and that shell is used to execute `shell -c 'touch file'` (also, the password used is the one of alice).

Comment: Generally speaking, the FreeBSD replacement for sudo is... sudo.  It's not in base system, but works in the exact same way, and is used by pretty much everyone except for folks who prefer doas (as I do; it's basically a _very_ simplified sudo).